# Can't get Google Plus API to work

Tags: javascript, json, google-plus

I have been trying to understand API for a while now. But i am just lost...

I am trying to do something as simple as to retrieve and display my Google Plus Tagline.

```
$.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/103039534797695934641?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", function(data) {

    html = data.nickname;

    // Insert the generated HTML to the DOM
    $('.shots').html(html);

});
```

What am i doing wrong?
Should i maybe insert a callback in the link - and if so, do you know how that is done?
I have tried all the ways i could think of.

Comment: Are you sure the key is rigth. Use Postman or another rest client to see the result

Comment: Yes, the key i the right one.

If you follow this link: https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/103039534797695934641?key=AIzaSyBaDZGM-uXuHc-VZZ2DINzVBcIDMN_54zg

then you can see what i should be getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using the [Google+ JavaScript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/javascript) sample to get going as opposed to performing XHRs against the endpoint, passing your API key... and effectively writing your own client library.

Also, if you are just interested in seeing what the API can do, you should start from [the Google APIs explorer for Google+](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/).

The following HTML does what you need:

```
<html>
  <body>
  </body>
  <script>
    var key = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
    function doStuff(){
      gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function(){
        gapi.client.setApiKey(key);
        gapi.client.plus.people.get({'userId': '103039534797695934641'}).execute(function(result){
          alert(result.tagline);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        });
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=doStuff"></script>
</html>
```

Note that I am using the Google-provided client library. You can explore some more by opening the console in your browser and browsing through the gapi.client.plus[...] methods.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need something more specific, all you need to do is change `data.nickname` to `data.tagline`:

```
$.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/103039534797695934641?key=AIzaSyBaDZGM-uXuHc-VZZ2DINzVBcIDMN_54zg", function(data) {
    var html = data.tagline;

    // Insert the generated HTML to the DOM
    $('.shots').html(html);
});
```

You can open the [URL](https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/103039534797695934641?key=AIzaSyBaDZGM-uXuHc-VZZ2DINzVBcIDMN_54zg) in a browser (Chrome/Firefox works for me) that is used in `$.getJSON` to view more properties that `data` contains such as `data.kind`, `data.nickname`, and `data.occupation`.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pjwXr/)